# Calculating Average daily Balance in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Starting with table;**

```
[AccountLedger]

AccountCode PostingDate            Amount    
128         2014-01-01 08:36:09    200.00
128         2014-01-01 14:18:10    200.00
128         2014-01-01 14:26:56      0.00
128         2014-01-01 18:17:31    400.00
128         2014-01-01 20:18:53    100.00
128         2014-01-02 00:10:35      0.00
128         2014-01-02 01:44:26    300.00
128         2014-01-02 15:49:31   -300.00
128         2014-01-03 00:33:23    400.00
128         2014-01-03 11:55:13   -200.00
128         2014-01-03 11:56:34   -100.00
128         2014-01-03 14:58:42   -400.00    
128         2014-01-03 17:31:11      0.00

**REQUIRED RESULT**

AccountCode PostingDate         daily_balance 
128         2014-01-01          900.00
128         2014-01-02          900.00
128         2014-01-03          600.00
```

**Query being appended**

```
select 
      Acc
    , Dte 
    , sum(daily_amt) over (PARTITION BY Acc ORDER BY Dte DESC) as daily_balance 
from (select 
            [AccountLedger].[AccountCode] as Acc
          , convert(date, [AccountLedger].[PostingDate])   as Dte
          , sum([AccountLedger].[Amount]) as daily_amt
      from [AccountLedger]
      WHERE [AccountLedger].[PostingDate] < '2014-04-01'
      and [AccountLedger].[AccountCode]=128

      group by  [AccountLedger].AccountCode
      , [AccountLedger].[PostingDate]

      ) t
       order by Acc, dte*
```

*But error appears;

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'order'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near 't'.*
```

**How can I get required result?**

Comment: What is order by acc, dte*?  What is dte* ?  in this case I believe the error message speaks volumes...and its pretty accurate.

Comment: This post shows no research effort.

Comment: Dte is posting date
the * sign appended wronfully while formating in text editor here.
The problem comes out of over clause; It works fine till "PARTITION BY Acc" and error arises out of "ORDER BY Dte DESC"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a simple date table (or in my case a udf to generate a date range)

```
Declare @DateR1 Date,@DateR2 Date
Set @DateR1 = '2014-01-01'
Set @DateR2 = '2014-01-31'


Select AccountCode
      ,PostingDate=Date2
      ,DailyBalance=sum(amount) 
 From  #Temp A
 Join (Select Date1=@DateR1,Date2=cast(RetVal as Date) from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date](@DateR1,@DateR2,'DD',1)) B on cast(PostingDate as Date) between Date1 and Date2
 Group By AccountCode,Date2 
 Order By 1
```

Returns

```
AccountCode PostingDate DailyBalance
128         2014-01-01  900
128         2014-01-02  900
128         2014-01-03  600
128         2014-01-04  600
128         2014-01-05  600
128         2014-01-06  600
...
128         2014-01-31  600
```

The UDF

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date] (@DateFrom datetime,@DateTo datetime,@DatePart varchar(10),@Incr int)

Returns 
@ReturnVal Table (RetVal datetime)

As
Begin
    With DateTable As (
        Select DateFrom = @DateFrom
        Union All
        Select Case @DatePart
               When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               End
        From DateTable DF
        Where DF.DateFrom < @DateTo
    )

    Insert into @ReturnVal(RetVal) Select DateFrom From DateTable option (maxrecursion 32767)

    Return
End

-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','DD',1) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2016-10-31','MI',15) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2016-10-02','SS',1)
```

Comment: You have reached exactly what I wanted, Actually I am very new to programming so can you please elaborate How can I apply this to my table (instead of udf) as given in question, Thanx in advance!

Comment: To be clear.  You do not want or can't use the UDF?  The UDF just generates a date range on-the-fly.   Another option would be to use a simple date table.   Either way, just let me know and I can help

Comment: I feel compelled to say these are Spot Balances, not Daily Averages.  You certainly can create Day Weighted Average Balances from the Spot Balance without having "fill-in the gaps"

Comment: Firstly coding for spot balances from AccountLedger as given in transaction table, then Taking average of spotBalance within specific date range. Thanx

Comment: I just realized that I didn't include the udf which generates the dynamic date range.  Let me know if you want it and I can modify my answer

Comment: Yes please, would you please use exact field names of given table instead of udf. Regards

Comment: I have voted dear, just 1 more reputation, and mine votes will be public. I am a beginner, hopefully will keep learning a lot from people like you here! :) :) :)

Comment: The dear thing makes me smile.

Answer (score 0):

your query works fine. but it does not do what you intend to, since you're grouping by datetime field and 2014-01-01 00:00:00 is different from 2014-01-01 00:00:01.

this is pretty simple way to aggregate amount based on date

`SELECT [AccountCode]
      ,cast([PostingDate] as date) as date
      ,sum([Amount]) as 'daily balance'
  FROM [AccountLedger]
  WHERE [PostingDate] < '2014-04-01'
  GROUP BY [AccountCode], cast([PostingDate] as date)`

Let me know if this works.

Comment: It works fine in my query too, The problem comes out of over clause; It works fine till "PARTITION BY Acc" and error arises out of "ORDER BY Dte DESC"

Comment: what purpose does "PARTITION BY Acc" serve ? Does my query not give you the results you need ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    AccountCode,
    convert(date, PostingDate) AS PostingDate,
    avg(Amount) as Average
from
  AccountLedger
where
  PostingDate < '2014-04-01'
group by
  AccountCode,
  convert(date, PostingDate)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/965ec/19